# Where to best configure proxy settings to "pip install" from inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am a bit new to using Docker and was wondering if there is a standard, or preference for passing proxy settings into a container.  Right now, I have a container that executes a single Python script.  As part of the build process I install python modules using pip install but, the command needs be aware of the proxy.  I doubt placing the proxy settings inside the Dockerfile is ideal, or in the docker-compose file.  Is there a better place to store these types of settings ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip inside dockerfile under proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277599/pip-inside-dockerfile-under-proxy)

Comment: `docker build --build-arg https_proxy=...` [is supported by default](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#predefined-args).